# MS Access: Query to Show Day's Total Based on Time

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm having a bit of difficulty in understanding a concept in MS Access Query. I'm not really good at queries. I just use the query builder to get my work done and thats where I'm stuck at this moment.

Here's the situation:

I have a transactions table that has the follwoing fields

**[Group], [Date Time], [Receipt Amount], [other fields...]**

Example:

[ABC]     [11/11/2013 20:15]    [120.00]

[DEF]     [12/11/2013 06:10]    [200.00]

[ABC]     [12/11/2013 06:20]    [10.00]

[ABC]     [12/11/2013 06:50]    [400.00]

My reporting requirement is to show the days total amount based on dd/mm/yy 06:30 to dd/mm/yy 06:29.

So, 11/11/2013 total should be calculated on transactions falling under 11/11/2013 06:30 till 12/11/2013 06:29.

I can't seem to write a query that can take a reporting date and give every group's day total based on time bounds. Furthermore, each group can have different time bounds. I tried using a lookup table but can't seem to move forward.

I'll be thankful for any help. I'll gladly explain more if required.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create a saved query in Access named [transactionsWithEffectiveDate].

For [transactions]

```
Group  Date Time            Receipt Amount
-----  -------------------  --------------
ABC    2013-11-11 20:15:00             120
DEF    2013-11-12 06:10:00             120
ABC    2013-11-12 06:20:00              10
ABC    2013-11-12 06:49:00             400
ABC    2013-11-12 06:50:00             200
ABC    2013-11-12 06:51:00             250
```

and [groups]

```
Group  StartTime
-----  ---------
ABC    06:50:00 
DEF    05:30:00
```

the query

```sql
SELECT 
    Group, 
    [Date Time], 
    [Receipt Amount],
    DateAdd("d", IIf(DateDiff("s", NewDayStart, [Date Time]) < 0, -1, 0), CDate(Int(t.[Date Time]))) AS EffectiveDate
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            t.Group, 
            t.[Date Time], 
            t.[Receipt Amount],
            CDate(Int(t.[Date Time]) + (g.StartTime - Int(g.StartTime))) AS NewDayStart
        FROM
            transactions t
            INNER JOIN
            groups g
                ON g.Group = t.Group
    )
```

returns

```
Group  Date Time            Receipt Amount  EffectiveDate
-----  -------------------  --------------  -------------
ABC    2013-11-11 20:15:00             120  2013-11-11   
DEF    2013-11-12 06:10:00             120  2013-11-12   
ABC    2013-11-12 06:20:00              10  2013-11-11   
ABC    2013-11-12 06:49:00             400  2013-11-11   
ABC    2013-11-12 06:50:00             200  2013-11-12   
ABC    2013-11-12 06:51:00             250  2013-11-12
```

You can then use that query as the basis for your subsequent queries and reports, e.g.,

```sql
SELECT 
    EffectiveDate, 
    Sum([Receipt Amount]) AS [SumOfReceipt Amount]
FROM transactionsWithEffectiveDate
GROUP BY EffectiveDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not quite sure if i am getting the syntax for msaccess right, but i suggest you shift the [Date Time] back 6 hours 30 minutes and use that as your business day.

```
select 
  [Group]
, DateAdd("h",-6,DateAdd("n",-30,[Date Time])) AS [Business Day]
, sum([Receipt Amount]) AS [Receipt Amount Sum]
from yourTable
group by 
  [Group]
, DateAdd("h",-6,DateAdd("n",-30,[Date Time]));
```

Comment: Thanks! It is a good answer. But I would have to either edit or create a new query for each group that has different time bounds. For example DEF could have 07:00 to 06:59 bounds.

Comment: if you have different times for each group, i suggest you set up a table with groups and their starting times. you can then join it to the transactions and do the calculation groupwise.